# Skim-coating LVL beam

Tags: drywall, drywall-mud

I have an LVL beam which I would like to skim-coat with drywall mud. My drywall guy is unsure whether that will be a durable solution and is recommending 1/4" drywall.

What's the general experience doing this, i.e. can an LVL beam be successfully skim-coated?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Paint

Answer (score 2):

Forget the mud.

Sand, patch little bits with wood filler if needed, prime and paint.